# initialize field value to zero?

Tags: database, ssms

Hey guys here is what I have to do:

Write and execute the proper SQL commands to add a field (name: num_rentals datatype: int) to the MOVIES table. You will also need to initialize the field value to zero for all existing records in the MOVIES table.

The table movies already exist so all I did was:

ALTER TABLE movies
ADD num_rentals INT;

But I'm not sure what they mean by initialize all field value to zero for all exisiting records in the movies table.... I'm sure its something simple that I just overlooked.

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE movies ADD num_rentals INT;
UPDATE Movies SET num_rentals = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The DEFAULT constraint is used to provide a default value for a column.

```sql
ALTER TABLE movies ADD num_rentals INT DEFAULT 0;
```